# Reporting Services - Giving a formula through Parameters

Tags: parameters, reporting, service, formula

I'm using SSRS 2008,
I'm building big reports and I use subreports, I need to give a formula by paramaters to a report.
How can I do it ?

I though about doing reflection on the parameters in order to use it like a formula.
Do you have any ideas if it'll work ?

Regards,

ps : sorry for my  bad english.